# Confused about drawables and bitmaps (Android)

Tags: android, drawable

I am a beginner developer and I am a little confused about drawables and bitmaps. From my current understanding:

-Bitmaps are like empty images (without a type yet?)
-Drawables are images that I can draw on them

What I want to do in the first place is to open a red image I made and then draw on it. How can I do that?

Also, all drawables must be placed in the 3 drawable folders, right?

By the way, what's the different of "assets" and "res" folder?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A drawable might be a bitmap, but maybe a shape

drawable is more general

assets holds file data

res holds (xml) defined data

Just some answers to your bunch of questions